# Invalid password when checking in .p12 certificate on android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, certificate, pkcs#12

With OpenSSL I created a certificate using the following.

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myKey.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes`

=> Hitting enter on all prompts

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey myKey.pem -in cert.pem -name "alias" -passout pass:123`

=>Transferring `keyStore.p12` and `cert.pem` to my android device (S10+)

=>Checked in `cert.pem` in settings

Then I tried to check In `keyStore.p12`: android settings > Biometrics and Security > Other Security Settings > Install from device storage > VPN and app user certificate > typed in the password “123”

Android returns “Invalid Password” but I know the password is correct (double checked it on my windows machine)

I've already tried to leave the password blank, restarted my phone and computer, generated a new certificate and verified the password multiple times etc.

I´m really at a loss here. thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer on accident.
I installed "Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1n" and created the certificate wth that version instead of "Win64 OpenSSL v3.0.2", which resolved the problem

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the option `-legacy` to `openssl pkcs12`.

Comment: Saved me! I was creating a p12 archive on MacOS Ventura and I couldn't get a Java app to descrypt it. This `-legacy` option was exactly what I needed.